# Search GitHub for Android apps and sort by stars

Tags: search, github

I want to search GitHub for repos of Android apps, and sort by stars. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

Almost.

You can search for Android apps based on the fact that they all contain an AndroidManifest.xml file in the repository.

Part of that XML will include some fragment of code similar to:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

So you need to search that, like so:

> "android:minSdkVersion" extension:xml

This will only bring up the files that match, so you'll need to click on the repository name that shows alongside the AndroidManifest.xml part in each search result.

You can't sort or filter by amount of stars though.